# Easy way to connect to a VPN in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

I am using Ubuntu [19.10](/questions/tagged/19.10). I am new to Linux OS and it is very hard for me even to install a single program. So, I am finding the easiest way to connect to a VPN which I can implement at my level.

Comment: In Ubuntu, go to Settings and type VPN in the search box. VPN is under the network section and you can add a VPN connection there.

Comment: Do you have any particular VPN in mind? Your work VPN? Privacy VPN?

Answer (score 0):

To install `openvpn`, use `apt install openvpn`
To connect via terminal, use `sudo openvpn --config <config file> --daemon` (--daemon is optional, use it to make the process keep running in the background instead of keeping the terminal open)

That's the method I use.  You could probably install an openvpn GUI though :)